# Game on widescreen display

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL development for MacOS.

I make game 1024x768 resolution. In the fullscreen mode on widescreen monitors my game looks streched, it's not good.
Is there any function in OpenGL to get pixel per inch value? If I find it, I can decide whether to add bars to the sides of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is a graphics library, which means that it is not meant to perform such tasks, its only for rendering something on to the screen. It is quite low level. You could use the Cocoa API NSScreen in order to get the correct information about the connected screens of your Mac.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think that way )

Answer (score 1):

> I make game 1024x768 resolution.

That's the wrong approach. Never hardcode any resolutions. If you want to make a fullscreen game, use the fullscreen resolution. If you want to adjust the rendering resolution, switch the screen resolution and let the display do the proper scaling. By using the resolutions offered to you by the display and OS you'll always get proper aspect ratio.

Note that it still may be neccessary to take pixel aspect ratio into account. However neither switching the display resolution, nor determining the pixel aspect ratio is part of OpenGL. Those are facilities provided by the OS.